# Commerce file description not showing

Tags: commerce, files

I'm using Commerce License and Commerce Files to sell digital downloads (zip files). Usually this works completely fine, so I'm thinking this might be a bug on my site on not in the modules themselves - but I'm not sure.

On one specific product the file description (and therefore the download link) doesn't appear on the user's file tab.

The orders that needs to download are in 'pre-order' paid state (using Commerce Pre-oder, which isn't a problem on other products on our site.

Here's the pre-order rule in case that's causing this:

```
{ "commerce_preorder_checkout_complete_generate" : {
    "LABEL" : "Generate pre-order pending orders on checkout completion",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "WEIGHT" : "10",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "Commerce Pre-order" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_preorder", "commerce_checkout" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_checkout_complete" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-order" ], "field" : "commerce_preorder_order" } },
      { "data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "commerce-order:commerce-preorder-order" ] } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_preorder_generate_pending_orders" : {
          "USING" : { "commerce_order" : [ "commerce-order" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "pending_orders" : { "pending_orders" : "Pending orders" } }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas as to how to investigate the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the rules that change the order state into: 'pre-order'.
This would be my first guess that the rules are not configured ok.
Hope that i helped.

Comment: thanks for the input. I've inserted that rule in the original question. But since it works on other pre-order products I'm thinking it's caused by something else?